# Coverage returning %NaN% when running unit tests in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, cobertura, coverlet

I have a dot net core version: '3.0.100', building on 'ubuntu-latest' and am trying to get code coverage reports.

I have been using Coverlet to generate Cobertura files which can then use the PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 to publish to the Devops pipelines code coverage viewer.

I have used one stage name build for building the project and generating artifacts and published them.
In another stage named unit tests i will be downloading the artifacts and using the artifacts of previous build.

But when I run unit tests by specifying the working directory where these artifacts were downloaded
Everything went fine up to this point,but when it is generating the code coverage reports in the unit test job it is generating NaN% value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxOSy.png)

I have tried all possible ways playing with working path directory and restoring the nuget packages.But No Luck None worked for me. I have even searched for this issue,I found one but that didn't worked me

When i tried to run the build and unit tests in one stage itself it successfully generated the code coverage reports,but placing that in another stage and downloading the previous build artifacts made me run into the issue.

How would I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you use `Vstest task` or `Powershell script` to generate Cobertura files? You could share the pipeline definition about the Build Step and Test Step. Maybe you could refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/503#issuecomment-520112616).